# How to limit the access to a class variable

Tags: swift, class

I'm pretty new to Swift and am wondering if there's anyway I can limit a variable so that nobody (no other classes) can set a new value, but is able to read the value?

```
class SomeClass {
    public someValue: Bool = false // but I do not want 'someValue' to be updated other than the class owns it.
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
public private(set) someValue: Bool = false
```

This allows other classes to read `someValue` but does not allow them to write to that variable.

Comment: `false` is implicitly a `Bool`.

Comment: I just copied the code from the question.